# List functions in a function

Tags: r, function

Is there a way in R to list the functions that are contained in a given function?

For instance in the code below:

```
myFun <- function(x) { 
  res <- list(m1=mean(x), s1=sd(x), mi=min(x))
  return(res)
}
```

How to extract from the function myFun the names of the functions used. In this case I would like to have a vector with mean, sd and min.

I would like to do this without having to call the function (otherwise Rprof() would do the job).

Comment: This is quite a nontrivial task. The only idea I have is to parse `body(myFun)` somehow, with `lsf.str("package:base")` maybe? Probably an overkill.

Comment: There's another problem: how would you choose between, say, `mean`, and `return`? Both are functions from `base`: `grep(ls("package:base"), pattern='return')`, `grep(ls("package:base"), pattern='mean')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install `pryr` via devtools and github:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("hadley/pryr")
```

Then simply walk into Mordor:

```
fun_calls(myFun)
[1] "{"      "<-"     "list"   "mean"   "sd"     "min"    "return"
```

Note how there are more functions than you expected, because so much in R is a function. Feel free to apply extra logic to remove common things you aren't interested in, like `{` and `<-` (which you get when you do an assign with `=`) and `[` (which you get if you ever subset).

Comment: Another neat tool I didn't know about!  I guess I'll have to learn how to browse the R-section of github.

Comment: `pryr` is used in Hadley's advanced R book, online.